# MacBook Pro 16" 2019 doesn't enter standby mode

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, power, pmset

After updating to macOS Sonoma my MacBook Pro 16" 2019 doesn't enter standby mode even at night after more than 10 hours of being closed.

`pmset -g assertions` shows the following:

```
2023-10-01 09:28:52 +0300 
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 171(WindowServer): [0x000006ec000988b8] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:100001e59 service:AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2 product:Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 120 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

Google says, that there is nothing abnormal. I've set the following settings in `pmset`
long time ago, and before update everything was fine:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              0
 lowpowermode         1
 standbydelayhigh     18000
 proximitywake        0
 standby              1
 standbydelaylow      3600
 ttyskeepawake        0
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 35
 displaysleep         2
 womp                 0
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                2
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         0
 acwake               0
 disksleep            7
```

One can see `standbydelayhigh` to be equal to 5 hours, hence, the laptop is expected to
enter standby mode after 5 hours of sleeping, but it doesn't:

[image]

The picture shows a battery statistic for a whole period of time. Before update this statistic had a gap, because it was not collected during standby. One more evidence is that there is a catastrophic battery drain of 5 or 6 percents, i.e. the laptop consumes power while being closed. Before update the battery percentage decreases by the same 5 or 6 percents during a several days (compare with one night after update).

Furthermore, before update I have to press a power button after opening a lid, because the laptop was in standby mode. Now the screen needs a very few time to show lockscreen without pressing the power button. Hence, the laptop doesn't enter standby.

I looked at activity monitor, nothing prevents sleep there. `pmset` shows the same, i.e. nothing prevents sleep. I've tried to reset SMC and PRAM, but it didn't help.

Bluetooth, Wi-Fi and Airdrop were disabled, when I closed the lid.

I can't figure out, what else I can do to resolve the problem.

Comment: I've been having the same problem since "upgrading" to Sonoma.